# Can I use the word "escape" instead of "escapism" in this context?

Tags: word-usage

> I want to escape from school and I love with this "escapism".

Can I use escape in place of escapism?

Similarly can I use escapism instead of escape in this sentence?

> Romantic novel should present an "escape" from dreary realities of life.

Both escapism and escape are nouns. So can I choose any of them? If I interchange would the meaning will be same or altered?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to express with your sentence? What makes you believe that you might be able to use these two words interchangeably? (other than the fact they are both nouns) Cat and catfish are both nouns, but they aren't synonyms.

Comment: as they both are nouns so can I use these two words interchangeably?

Comment: Would it mean same when I use interchangeably or it will change the meaning of sentence?

Comment: What did you find when you looked in the dictionary? What makes you think the meaning of those two words is the same?

Comment: I found them as nouns, so I thought to use interchangeably. Rest I want to understand from native speakers like you.

Answer (score 1):

The noun "**[escapism](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/escapism)**" has only one definition - *a way of avoiding an unpleasant or boring life, especially by thinking, reading, etc. about more exciting but impossible activities*.

The noun "**[escape](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/escape)**" has several definitions - *the act of successfully getting out of a place or a dangerous or bad situation*; *a loss that happens by accident*; *something that helps you to forget about your usual life or problems*.

As you can see the 3rd definition of "**escape**" and the definition of "**escapism**" are similar, yet, I wouldn't say that they are the same.

Take the second example, it can be rewritten using either word:

- Romantic novels should present an **escape** from dreary realities of life.
- Romantic novels should be a form of **escapism** for those tired of dreary realities of life.

Comment: I would take issue with your last sentence, specifically the phrase **be an escapism**: *Romantic novels should be an escapism for those tired of dreary realities of life.*  People who read such fiction are indulging in escapism, but it is not idiomatic to call the novels themselves  *an escapism*.  You could say "The novels are a form of escapism".

Comment: Escapism is analogous to racism in that regard.   A novel may be *racist* but not ***a** racism*.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to escape from school and I [am in] love with this "escape."

The problem is that *this escape* would resolve to an actual single instance of you escaping, but you only mention an escape you want to do.

You can't say *this escape* unless there was an actual escape.  You can say *this desire to escape* or *this want to escape.*

*Escapism* means something different than *escape* and is not really related to a physical escape as in breaking free from a place.  It means the overall tendency indulging in fantasies unrelated to reality in order to avoid reality.  Escapism would be something like:

> I often daydream that I'm a cartoon rabbit in a TV show.  And other things.  I am in love with my escapism.

---

> Similarly can I use escapism instead of escape in this sentence?

*Escapism* is an -ism that isn't used to describe specific things, but rather an overall tendency of a person.  A person wanting to indulge in escapism will do certain things, but it's odd to say doing certain things gives or provides escapism.